# Remove 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: facebook

Hi how can I solve this problem:

- This website should have an FB Page Like button: https://www.superheroesshare.com/de/
- It worked before without problems. It also works in other countries Russia, USA.
- Now since short there was realised that the FB Like Button is not shown anymore, because of this problem:
  "Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'"

How would you solve the problem?
I am sure it comes from FB but not from the Server, since it works in other countries.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/4007695022654997/

Comment: Thanks, I will follow the updates there.